# Find closed formula for the exponential generating function of sequence counting permutations with 2 cycles.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, closed-form, stirling-numbers, permutation-cycles

Find a closed formula for the exponential generating function of $\{c(n,2)\}_{n\geq2}$, that is the sequence counting permutations of length $n$ that consist of $2$ cycles.

My approach: The exponential generating function for Stirling Numbers of the First Kind,
$$
C(n,k) = \sum_{n=k}^{+\infty}{c(n,k)} \, \frac{x^n}{n!} 
= \frac{\log^k(1/(1-x))}{k!}
$$

Replacing $k$ with $2$,
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} c(n,2) \, \frac{x^n}{n!} 
= \frac{1}{2!} \biggl( \log \frac{1}{1-x} \biggr)^2 
$$

Using
$$
\log \frac{1}{1-x} = x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots{}
$$
we have
$$
\biggl( \log \frac{1}{1-x} \biggr)^2 
= \biggl( x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots{} \biggr) 
\biggl( x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots{} \biggr)
$$

Now $c(n,2)$ is given by the coefficient of $\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ in $C(x)$

Hence,
$$
c(n,2) = \frac{1}{2!} \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{n!}{k(n-k)}
$$

I may be dead wrong about this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you already check it for n=2,3,4,5 ?

Comment: I think a permutation of length n that consists of 2 cycles can be represented by a n-bit string. the 0 represents the elements of one cycle, the 1 the elements of the other cycle.  The 0-String and the 1-String are not valid representatonsthere are always 2 representations for such a permutations, so the number of all such permutation is $2^{n-1}-1$, I think

Comment: @miracle173 I think $2^{n-1}$ doesn't hold for n = 4, as there are 10 permutations of length 4 with 2 cycles but this gives 15.

Comment: I already corrected my comment and the formula. But I can't see 10 permutations of length 4, I see only these seven: 1 234, 2 134, 3 124, 4 123, 12 34, 13 24, 14 23

Comment: Oh I understand now. My bad.

Comment: Can you show how it can be derived from the exponential generating function?

Comment: sorry, I didn't check your proof

Comment: @miracle173 In the Wikipedia article on Stirling Numbers of the First Kind, they show that c(4,2) = 11. Link - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Signs

Comment: @Phicar Hi, I wanted to ask if my approach was correct and the closed formula I found was the right one. Also, is there a way to find this without using generating function?

Comment: @lettuce ok, I have answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct, to finish notice that $\frac{1}{k(n-k)}=\frac{1}{n}\left (\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{n-k}\right )$ and adding over $k$ you get twice $H_{n-1}.$
For a combinatorial way, choose the elements that you want in the cycle containing one, say of size $k$ in $\binom{n-1}{k}$ ways. Notice that when you pick the elements there are $k!$ possible cycles (by fixing $1$ as the minimal element and permuting the other elements in all ways), the rest $n-k$ elements are in the other cycle and there are $(n-k-1)!$ to arrange it. Adding over $k$ you get
$$\sum _{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{k}k!(n-k-1)!=\sum _{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{(n-1)!}{(n-k)}=(n-1)!H_{n-1}.$$